# How to modify htaccess url rewrite just how facebook does

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to automatically gather up a respective path name to the users input so for example with facebook.

A user creates a page/user profile with the name JohnDoe777 thus their url is: facebook.com/JohnDoe777.

How can one do that? I know it deals with the .htaccess file but I need careful instructions on how to do it so in case I don't mess anything up on my local server.

Comment: The situation doesn't require rewrite to work. In fact, it is more efficient not to use rewrite if you can do it in some other way that involves a process that is going to be executed anyway. For instance, if your site is in PHP, and so, PHP is going to work any way, add efficient parsing rules to the PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

It is what we call URL rewriting.

You can find a good example here

http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with rewrite, although it may be done with rewrite rules.

In FaceBook, and a ton of other sites, you can access information just by what is typed on the URL by parsing that information on a PHP/ASP/JSP/perl/etc file. The idea is that when some data is stored, a unique URL is assigned to that set of data. Then the data can be accessed by using that URL.

This pseudocode helps to get the idea

```
data = false;

requested_url = 'http://www.example.com/JohnDoe777';

data_to_retrieve = JohnDoe777

check_if_data_in_database = query_the_database_for( 'JohnDoe777' );

if ( check_if_data_in_database === false ) {
    check_if_data_in_file = look_for_file( 'JohnDoe777' );
}

if ( data !== false ) {
    process_and_present_data( 'JohnDoe777' );
}

if ( data === false ) {
    tell_user_an_error_happened_or_no_data_available
}
```

Of course you can do a rewrite for something like

```
example.com/JohnDoe777
```

to

```
example.com/index.php?user=JohnDoe777
```

But both methods work for gathering/presenting data that has been created and stored and the rewrite step is just an extra, common, but not necessary.